# PlatformException(ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL, The email address is badly formatted., null)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I am creating a app using flutter and firebase. but when i am trying to create a user instance it is showing this error:-  "PlatformException(ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL, The email address is badly formatted., null)"
I am attaching the code.///////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
import 'package:chatbox/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:chatbox/services/database.dart';
import 'package:chatbox/views/chatRoom.dart';
import 'package:chatbox/widgets/widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function toggle;
  SignUp(this.toggle);
  @override
  _SignUpState createState() => _SignUpState();
}

class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
  bool isLoading = false;
  DatabaseMethods databaseMethods=new DatabaseMethods();
  AuthMethods authMethods = new AuthMethods();
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController userNameTextEditingController =
      new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailTextEditingController =
      new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordTextEditingController =
      new TextEditingController();
  signMeUp() async {
    if(formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      Map<String,String> userInfoMap={
        "email": emailTextEditingController.text,
        "name" : userNameTextEditingController.text,

      };
      setState(() {
        isLoading =true;
      });
      authMethods.signUpWithEmailAndPassword(emailTextEditingController.text, passwordTextEditingController.text)
      .then((val){
      //  print("${val.uid}");

        databaseMethods.uploadUserInfo(userInfoMap);

        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context)=>chatRoom(),
        ));


      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBarMain(context),

      body: isLoading ? Container(
        child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) ,
      ) : SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 50,
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
          child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
            Form(
              key: formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    validator: (val) {
                      return val.isEmpty || val.length < 2 ? "invalid" : null;
                    },
                    controller: userNameTextEditingController,
                    style: simpleTextstyle(),
                    decoration: textFieldInputDecoration("username"),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    validator: (val){
                      return RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+").hasMatch(val) ? null : "Enter correct email";
                    },
                    controller: emailTextEditingController,
                    style: simpleTextstyle(),
                    decoration: textFieldInputDecoration("email"),

                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                  validator:  (val) {
                    return val.length < 6
                        ? "Enter Password 6+ characters"
                        : null;
                  },
                    controller: passwordTextEditingController,
                    style: simpleTextstyle(),
                    obscureText: true,

                    decoration: textFieldInputDecoration("password"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            Container(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                  child: Text(
                    "forget password",
                    style: simpleTextstyle(),
                  ),
                )),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                signMeUp();
              },
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                      const Color(0xff007EF4),
                      const Color(0xff2A75BC)
                    ]),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
                child: Text(
                  "Sign up",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
              child: Text(
                "Sign up with google",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 17),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Already have an account?",
                  style: meadiumTextstyle(),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                    widget.toggle();
                  },
                  child: Container(

                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                    child: Text("Sign in Now",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 17,
                          decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 60,
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume email is correct 
From issue https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1760#issuecomment-570766212 and https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1760#issuecomment-613303831

email text field value might contain white space
You can use `emailTextEditingController.text.trim()` 
code snippet

```
authMethods.signUpWithEmailAndPassword(emailTextEditingController.text.trim(), passwordTextEditingController.text)
...
Map<String,String> userInfoMap={
        "email": emailTextEditingController.text.trim(),
        "name" : userNameTextEditingController.text,

      };
```

You can also use package https://pub.dev/packages/email_validator to validate email 
code snippet

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:email_validator/email_validator.dart';

void main() {
    const String email = 'fredrik.eilertsen@gail.com';
    final bool isValid = EmailValidator.validate(email);

    print('Email is valid? ' + (isValid ? 'yes' : 'no'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because your email id is not in the correct format. Try editing your email id.
In your email validator add this.

```
Validator(val){
  if(!val.contains("@")){
     retrun enter a valid email}
  else{ return null}
}
```